# What's the purpose of the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.StartConstructor token?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

The `JsonToken` `enum` in `Newtonsoft.Json` `namespace` contains, among others, the entry `JsonToken.StartConstructor`.

I most likely misinterpret the meaning of this token, as I take it for granted that JS's constructor methods are not valid in JSON, the same as there are no `function`, expression, or `var` tokens.

So how would a constructor be manifested in JSON, if that's what it is?

Comment: e.g. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonReader.htm

Comment: Related: [JConstructor and JRaw in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36958680/3744182).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the [`ParseTests` source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/26d887125453cfd85c08f81a48f2d4d6a51d4a2d/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/JsonTextReaderTests/ParseTests.cs), it looks like it's so that you can have JSON like this:

```
{ "date": new Date(2017, 2, 10) }
```

... which isn't actually valid JSON, but may be common in the wild.

Comment: similar example is found in a link from stuartd: `{ "Constructor": new Date(2000, 12, 30)  }`, but if I read well, that linked piece of code is actually a formatter that outputs such 'json'