# JRaw SelectToken returns null

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 in .Net core 2.0.

If i use JObject, i am able to `SelectToken` like so:

```
JObject.Parse("{\"context\":{\"id\":42}}").SelectToken("context.id")
```

Returns

> 42

However, if i use JRaw, i get null for the same path?

```
new JRaw("{\"context\":{\"id\":42}}").SelectToken("context.id")
```

returns

> null

Due to how my code is setup, my model is already in JRaw, and converting it to JObject just to select this token seems like a waste of RAM (this call is on the hot path).

**UPDATE**
Ok, my actual data comes down in a model where only one of the properties is JRaw, so i need something like the below to work:

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JRaw>>(
 "{\"a\":{\"context\":{\"id\":42}}}")["a"].SelectToken("context.id")
```

The above returns null again.

Comment: try this => `JRaw.Parse("{\"context\":{\"id\":42}}").SelectToken("context.id")` is same as => `JToken.Parse("{\"context\":{\"id\":42}}").SelectToken("context.id");`

Comment: you can use both of above to get specific token from your `raw` json

Comment: @ershoaib very nice! Unfortunately, this highlighted that i oversimplified the examples provided, please see the update

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use `.SelectToken` with a `JRaw` instance.

Comment: @RuiJarimba but the method is on the class: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw.htm?

Comment: `JRaw raw = ....; JToken.Parse(raw.Value.ToString()).SelectToken("context.id").Value<int>()`

Comment: @RuiJarimba Yes i can do that, but that creates an extra allocation in memory, and if JSON is huge, this is double RAM

Comment: @zaitsman yes the method is there, but it probably doesn't make sense for `JRaw` object. If you add a watch to a variable of type `JRaw` you'll check that many properties are `null`, `HasValue` is `false` and properties such as `First` and `Last` throw an `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182188/discussion-between-rui-jarimba-and-zaitsman).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JConstructor and JRaw in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958680/jconstructor-and-jraw-in-json-net)

Comment: @shA.t I don't think this question is a duplicate of that one

Comment: If you are deserializing JSON (rather than constructing from scratch using already-serialized JSON objects) then `JRaw` may not give you improved performance.  When deserializing, [`JsonSerializerInternalReader`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L219) calls [`JRaw.Create()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JRaw.cs#L59) which parses the JSON and copies it to a `JsonTextWriter`.  Writing to a `JTokenWriter` may be just as fast, with faster postprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title might be a bit misleading, but basically what the OP needs is a way to parse an existing (and large) `JRaw` object without consuming too much memory.

I ran some tests and I was able to find a solution using a `JsonTextReader`.

I don't know the exact structure of the OP's json strings, so I'll assume something like this:

```
[
  {
    "context": {
      "id": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "context": {
      "id": 20
    }
  },
  {
    "context": {
      "id": 30
    }
  }
]
```

Result would be an integer array with the id values (10, 20, 30).

## Parsing method

So this is the method that takes a `JRaw` object as a parameter and extracts the Ids, using a `JsonTextReader`.

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetIds(JRaw raw)
{
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(raw.Value.ToString()))
    using (var textReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
    {
        while (textReader.Read())
        {
            if (textReader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && textReader.Value.Equals("id"))
            {
                int? id = textReader.ReadAsInt32();

                if (id.HasValue)
                {
                    yield return id.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example I'm assuming there is one and only one type of object with an id property.

There are other ways to extract the information we need - e.g. we can check the token type and the path as follows:

```
if (textReader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer && textReader.Path.EndsWith("context.id"))
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(textReader.Value);
    yield return id;
}
```

## Testing the code

I created the following C# classes that match the above json structure, for testing purposes:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("context")]
    public Context Context { get; set; }

    public Data(int id)
    {
        Context = new Context
        {
            Id = id
        };
    }
}

public class Context
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a JRaw object and extracting the Ids:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JRaw rawJson = CreateRawJson(); 
        List<int> ids = GetIds(rawJson).ToList(); 

        Console.Read();
    }

    //  Instantiates 1 million Data objects and then creates a JRaw object
    private static JRaw CreateRawJson()
    {
        var data = new List<Data>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1_000_000; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new Data(i));
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        return new JRaw(json);
    }
}
```

## Memory Usage

Using Visual Studio's Diagnostic tools I took the following snapshots, to check the memory usage:

[image: Memory Usage screenshot]

- Snapshot #1 was taken at the beginning of the console application (low memory as expected)
- Snapshot #2 was taken after creating the JRaw object

  > JRaw rawJson = CreateRawJson();
- Snapshot #3 was taken after extracting the ids

  > List ids = GetIds(rawJson).ToList();